# JComponent: how to set maximum width?

Tags: java, swing, size, jcomponent

I need to make `JComponent`'s width to be `300` or less, but height should be variable (depending on content of `JComponent`).

Firstly, I tried to use

```
myComponent.setMaximumSize(300, 9999);
```

but I found that this method has absolutely no effect, and component still becomes expanded depending on its content (I can't see any effect, at least).

Then I tried to use

```
myComponent.setPreferredSize(300, (int)myComponent.getPreferredSize().getHeight());
```

Then, width becomes 300 and not less than 300. This isn't perfect, but acceptable. BUT, now, when component's content is changed, size isn't changed! This isn't acceptable.

I tried to find the way to affect only preferred width, and leave height to be "default", but I failed to find that way.

I tried to set height to 0 or -1: no effect.

How to achieve that?

---

UPD: please take a look at the picture: http://goo.gl/3Hp59   That's what I already implemented, but I used `setPreferredSize()`, which is bad, as I already realized, thank you.

Please help me find out the correct way:

Currently I use `GridBagLayout`. I need to make right column's width <= 300. (and left one, say, <= 200) How to achieve that using `GridBagLayout`, or what layout should I use instead?

Comment: don't even try to tweak the min/pref/max - providing reasonable sizing hints is the exclusive task of the component itself ([see a recent thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519)). So implement them to report such reasonable values - and then choose a LayoutManager which dis/respects them as you to your requirements.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @kleopatra, ok, I realized that I should not use setPreferredSize() etc, but please help me to find out the correct way: I updated my question, check it.

Comment: @kleopatra, after all, thanks for getting me out from the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html).  It has some the best controls for sizing.  GroupLayout can look a bit intimidating, but the examples provided are excellent.  Especially useful if you want to allow the user to resize the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much, currenly i'm playing with it and it seems to be exactly what I need, really. More, your guess was correct: I want to allow the user to resize the screen, and I couldn't achieve needed behavior with `GridBagLayout`, but I can with `GroupLayout`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

- from [Standard LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html): use `BoxLayout`
- [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) accepting `Mix,` `Max` and `PreferredSize`
- [don't set `Mix,` `Max` and `PreferredSize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi), every JComponent (excluding an empty `JPanel` (`Grapics/2D`), and a `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`) can properly return `XxxSize` by itself.

Comment: Ok, I realized that I should not use setPreferredSize() etc, but please help me to find out the correct way: I updated my question, check it.